# RabbitMQ/MQTT - incorrect memory high alert

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to connect a large number of clients(based on eclipse paho) to the MQTT broker.

I see an incorrect high memory watermark set often that slows down **subscribers** connecting to the broker.

This starts to happen at around 10k connections and slows down further connections.
At this point the %mem reported by all rabbitmq processes is < 30% of 8GB of RAM.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 31-Oct-2014::12:52:58 ===
vm_memory_high_watermark clear. Memory used:7420789416 allowed:7430278348

=WARNING REPORT==== 31-Oct-2014::12:52:58 ===
memory resource limit alarm cleared on node 'rabbit@jb-m01'
```

I have enabled hipe compile, but same is the situation even without.

All subscribers execute `connect()` method on a thread pool.

I have varied no. of threads at 20, 100, 200, at 20 or lower, the %cpu is sane ~ 60-80, at 100 and above I get to see ~ 200-300 sometimes. Even though the no. of connections doesnt grow (variate ~ 10K).

At this point I also see that the subscribers throw the following error.
Does this mean the broker is stalling due to overloaded?

```
Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:100)
    ... 1 more
```

Anything I need to cater either while writing the client / server config?

Thanks ...